# Spring Boot Application displays no error, but tomcat not initialized and application.properties is unused

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I created a new project using Spring Initializr, and opened it with Intellij IDEA version 2020.3.2 ide. After maven installed all dependencies in the pom.xml file, I ran the main method in the DemoApplication class. I didn't add anything new or different than the default project created by the Spring Initializr.

Two Problems occured:

1- Console outputted only these 3 logs, and Tomcat wasn't initialized

> 2021-02-03 23:48:45.073  INFO 15872 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication: Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_281 on DESKTOP-M with PID 15872 (D:\demo\target\classes started by M in D:\demo)

> 2021-02-03 23:48:45.078  INFO 15872 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication : No active profile set,falling back to default profiles: default

> 2021-02-03 23:48:46.355 INFO 15872 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication: Started DemoApplication in 2.062 seconds (JVM running for 2.87)

> Process finished with exit code 0

2- Anything I write in the application.properties file turns grey (unused)

I watched a lot of tutorials, and did exactly as they do. Their console output always has more than 3 statements and is even colored, which mine isn't

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Would appreciate it if you would help me figure out how to correctly run the project and have the server up and running.

Should I add anymore run Options?

[image]

External Libraries:

[image]

Comment: Have you got the "Include dependencies with Provided scope" option enabled in the run configuration for your application? Also, probably unrelated to your problem, but you don't need the `commons-logging` dependency and it may interfere with Boot's default logging dependencies.

Comment: There was an error in the console that stated that this class wasn't found, so I added it.

Comment: I enabled the "Include dependencies with Provided scope" option, but still nothing changed.

Comment: Please check, whether (simply) **`<packaging>jar</packaging>`** fixes this issue, and if you further *need* a war, please consult https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: @xerx593 Unfortunately I tried it and it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Do you see all the specified dependencies in the External Libraries section of the project view? You don't have the dependency versions specified.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, I edited the post with a screenshot of the External Libraries section

Comment: Do you run via Application or via Maven? Make sure https://i.imgur.com/97RdrDb.png option is disabled.

Comment: @CrazyCoder via Maven

Comment: Run without Maven using Run option on the left of the main method and [disable Maven delegation](https://i.imgur.com/97RdrDb.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder still same issue

Comment: Please zip and share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1. can reproduce!! (main class, run) solution: run (project) as (maven) `spring-boot:run`

Comment: yea: reproduced&fixed with 2020.3.2 "community edition"... i assume there a missing `spring-boot:repackage` behind the scenes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition which [has no support for Spring Boot](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

That is why the properties are not highlighted and the output is not colored.

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate will use [Spring Boot Run/Debug configuration type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y33QR.png) automatically:

[image: Boot]

As a workaround you can run your code via Maven `spring-boot:run`.

Comment: Running mvn spring-boot:run started up tomcat which was not happening via a standard run, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This issue is reproducible with a [simple war initializer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.2.RELEASE&packaging=war&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web), when you run `DemoApplication` with a "standalone java" (IDE run) configuration.

The solution/correct usage is: To run (the project) in a "maven" `spring-boot:run` (IDE run) configuration.

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behavior when I setup a project with pox.xml you provided.

The "Include dependencies with "Provided" fixed it for me. However I had to reload the Maven dependencies like this a few times: pom.xml (right click) -> Maven -> Reload Project.

I would still suggest that you remove `<scope>provided</scope>` in `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!-- Comment this out -->
<!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

Here is a good answer - [Java Spring Boot - spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency doesn't work with scope provided when running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137134/java-spring-boot-spring-boot-starter-tomcat-dependency-doesnt-work-with-scope)

If you still need this project to run in an external Tomcat container and thus want to mark the `spring-boot-spring-boot-starter` dependency as "provided", you can specify a separate profile for that configuration - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302247

Answer (score 0):

Worked on doing

1. Running code via Maven in Edit Configurations with command line as -> `spring-boot:run`.
2. In `pom.xml` changed `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>` to `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>`